# send data to ttyACM0 device

Tags: usb, microcontroller, tty

I'm trying to implement a function that whenever my ttyACM0 device receives a "hello\r", the LED will blink once.  It blinks by using the command:

```
 echo -e "hello\r" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

And here's my question:  does this command only write "hello\r" to the usb device?  I'm asking because when I try to do the same echo command again, my LED doesn't blink at all.  However, if I reset my device and echo "hello\rhello\rhello\r", it blinks three times. When I try to do the echo another time, it doesn't work again.

Hope someone could help.

~S

Comment: By the way, my goal is to do several echos to keep my LED blinking.  Thanks.

Comment: You need a -n too, otherwise you'll get an additional newline character.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't notice that!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Paul R, 
I should add a "-n" there

```
 echo -n -e "hello\r" > /dev/ttyACM0
```